# Lambda expression create unrelated compile error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, lambda, compiler-errors

Whenever I add a lambda expression (in the following form) to my wpf project, I get an error. The errors are nothing to do with the expression, but they arrive every time I add one.

here is my latest:

```
using ( LeisureServiceClient client = ServiceFactory.Instance.GetLeisureService() )
{
    client.Execute( ServiceFactory.Instance.ConnectionDetails, new MoveBasketItemsToAccountCommand()
    {
        BasketItemIDs = bisList.ToList().ConvertAll<Guid>( bis => bis.ID )
    } );
}
```

This seems perfectly valid to me, this gives the following compile error, highlighting `client` from `client.Execute(...)`.

```
Error 43: The type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
```

this code is nothing to do with a DependancyObject. Regardless, System.Windows is referenced in the .cs file, which also contains:

```
public class PointOfSaleViewModel : DependencyObject
```

which is quite happy to compile when the lambda expression is removed.

now, to add confusion... this is fine:

```
ServiceFactory.Instance.ShiftDataRefreshedEvent += ( s, e ) =>
{
    Account = new ObservableCollection<BasketItemSummary>( ServiceFactory.Instance.CurrentContact.Account );
    Basket = new ObservableCollection<BasketItemSummary>( ServiceFactory.Instance.Shift.OpenCurrentContact.Basket );
};
```

so, it's not the lambda expression itself that's causing the error, I'm out of ideas as to why this isn't compiling, and pretty keen to get some input before my head explodes.

**Update**

the alternate syntax suggested by a colleague

```
BasketItemIDs = bisList.ToList().ConvertAll( delegate( BasketItemSummary basketItem ) { return basketItem.ID; } )
```

also fails, giving the same compilation error.

Comment: Are you serializing anything in this? Perhaps with a WCF service? I get that error when the serialization process doesn't know about a type it is trying to serialize and need to add a [ServiceKnownType] attribute

Comment: I think your right here.. the BasketItemSummary comes from a wcf webservice. Good catch. I'm not programming the service tho (and WCF isn't my hot topic). But I'm told "the types are definitely there as otherwise you wouldn't have intellisense on BasketItemSummary", where there any other steps to get it to play nice with lambda?

Comment: System.Windows version 2.0.5.0 is a Silverlight assembly.  Are you using Silverlight anywhere?

Comment: Nope, not to my knowledge at least, I think Rachel is right.
I thought Silverlight didn't have DependancyObject anyway and u had to use INotifyPropertyChanged instead (IDK, just remember hearing that somewhere)

Comment: It's strange that the compiler is asking for this reference then.  You might want to add the reference and see if the compiler error goes away.  I don't know too much about SL, but DependencyObject is defined in System.Windows.

Comment: I faced a very similar issue today with a .NET 4.0 WPF project, referencing some silverlight libraries and using LINQ in the class. That resolved the issue: removing 'using System.Windows' from usage directives and changing the only occurence of 'Window' in code to 'System.Windows.Window' (so usage directive is not required any more because type is specified with a whole namespace). Basically nothing changed, but error disappeared. Awkward stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like `BasketItemSummary` (or one of the properties) exposes this dependency on the public API - perhaps it is a base-class for the type. Simply: add the missing reference as it instructs.

Comment: System.Windows is in the presentationFramework.dll/windowBase.dll, which are already referenced in the application, can't see that there is just a System.Windows in the [add reference] browser so I assume this is right. 

using System.Windows; is also at the top of the .cs file.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but in case someone else faces this problem:

Recently, I faced a problem much like yours. The solution I'm working includes a web project which has reference to a wpf project (for generating documents for downloading). After some modifications in the wpf project, the web project would not compile anymore, with the following error message:

```
Error   4   The type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

After some debugging, I figured out the error message only pointed to lines which involved LINQ operations (first I also thought it was related to lambdas, as you).

In the end, the root of the problem were some wpf's visual tree helper methods I had taken from http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/. I had taken the methods from LinqToVisualTree and put them under the "System.Linq" namespace. Seemingly that was somehow conflicting with the original Linq extension methods in my web project, and once I changed the namespace of the LinqToVisualTree methods to something else the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the dll in your project: right click on project, choose add reference.

Comment: at the time I wrote this, WindowsBase was referenced in the appropriate project.. It's not a problem anymore (and I apparently forgot to update this Q =/ [sry]).. I'll try to backwards engineer the fix, but IIRC I was a missing reference to System.Linq